# Getting error while using swagger-confluence jar. Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile swagger-confluence-CLI-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar

Tags: java, swagger, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have Java 8 installed in system and while running the below command getting the error.

Command:

```
"java -jar swagger-confluence-cli-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar -u "https://localhost/confluence/rest/api/" -b "dGVzdDp0ZXN0==" -g "true" -p "[CLI]" -i "true" -k "TEST" -s "swagger-petstore-example.yaml" -t "Swagger Pet Store" -m "single"
```

Tried with the 2.1 version also, but failed.

Comment: there seems to be something wrong with the jar, try downloading it again

Comment: already tried downloading it again. But still the same error.

Comment: Do you have Oracle JDK installed? Or you are using OpenJDK?

Comment: I have the same problem. Multiple downloads, different methods of downloads. Jar is corrupt. Normally I can open a jar file with an archive tool, but not this one. 
Using Ubuntu 17.10  

java --version  
openjdk 9-Ubuntu  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Found a mirror with a working JAR file
[Mirror](https://www.versioneye.com/java/net.slkdev.swagger.confluence:swagger-confluence-cli-all/2.2-RELEASE)